# Существую ли выпадающие списки в 1с управляемые формы

Tags: 1с

Есть ли возможность в 1с управляемые формы возможность сделать выпадающий список, как list в HTML. Раньше было модальное окно, со списком выбора, которое ужасно и устарело. Не смог найти совсем ничего кроме кривой неполной статьи http://1c-esse.buter.ru/vypadayushhij-spisok-na-forme.html

Answer (score 0):

```
СписокВыбора.ПоказатьВыборЭлемента()
ПоказатьВыборИзМеню()
```

и ещё третий есть, наподобие «ПоказатьВыборИзМеню»